# Resetting tinymce content based on parent component changes

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

I have a parent component that with in it i have couple directives. One directive contains another directive to display the tinymce form/content and another directive that has a list of selections. With each selection made the tinymce content is changed.

Currently i have in my parent component i make a selection change which goes to the parent and then to the directive containing the tinymce form. In my directive that contains the tinymce directive - i am calling

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(selectedItem);
```

even though this works and my tinymce form changes based on selection. I don't believe that i should be accessing the tinymce editor directly from the parent. Is there a way that i trigger the tinymce form change based on selection change?

Here is what i have.
Parent component html contains:

```
<selection-display [selectedItem]="selectionItem.data (onEdit)="onEdit($event)">  
   <tinymce-form [selectedItem]="selectionItem.data" (onChange)="changeSelection($event)"></tinymce-form>
</selection-display>

<selection-list (selectChange)="editSelection($event)"></selection-list>
```

In my selection-display directive i have  a method that will update the view by calling `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(selectedItem)` instead of passing the selected item to the tinymce-form directive.

How can i elimante the `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(selectedItem)` from the parent and have my tinymce directive handle content changes to display.